# Fixing arm-bend in rig

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation, weight-painting

I have followed tutorials, but I can't seem to make this sharp bend just right for a minecraft character.I changed the max and min amounts, but there is still a crooked line on the elbow.

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like your bend shape key isn't correctly connected to your armature

Comment: Did you use corrective shapekeys like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3JWNIkwBZ8

Comment: Not sure. let me check.

Comment: Just add some loop cuts around the elbow...

Comment: Where exactly? Let me upload a image of edit mode.

Comment: @ Paul I watched the video, but the regular pose of the arm expanded.